# MomentJS .format() produces correct date -1 day in my timezone

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I've noticed that when I use momentJs to output a date in a particular format in my timezone, that a day is lost.

I'm in the UTC-4:30 timezone.

This does not happen in all timezones; noted that this works properly in UTC-5:00 timezone.

The following are console.log results run consecutively:

**Correct output:**

```
moment([2013, 0, 24])
```

*Moment

  _a: Array[8]

  _d: Thu Jan 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0430 (Venezuela Standard Time)

  _isUTC: false

  _lang: false

  _proto: Object*

```
moment([2013, 0, 24]).toDate()
```

*Thu Jan 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0430 (Venezuela Standard Time)*

**Incorrect output:**

```
moment('01/24/2013').format('MM/DD/YYYY')
```

*"01/23/2013"*

```
moment([2013, 0, 24]).format('MM/DD/YYYY')
```

*"01/23/2013"*

Notice that once the .format() method is used, a day is lost and the 23rd is output instead of 24th.

Can anybody explain this behavior?  Again, it seems timezone specific.

Answer (score 0):

I set my time zone to `(UTC-4:30) Caracas`, and then checked the value of:

```
moment('01/24/2013').format('MM/DD/YYYY')
```

It properly returned `01/24/2013`, so I can't reproduce the problem you described.

I'm checking with moment.js 2.0.0. in Google Chrome 27.0.1453.116m running on Windows 8.

Perhaps this is related to an older version of moment.js.  Can you please verify?

Comment: where did you set the timezone?

Comment: @daydreamer - in the Windows operating system time zone settings.